# Copy innerHTML to clipboard from multiple <li> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to create a greasemonkey script to copy the `innerHTML` of some `<li>` elements, but I'm unable to to so because it is a nodelist.

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".bx li");
GM_setClipboard(list.innerHTML)
```

Comment: whatever operation you want to do with all af the `li`, iterate the list first and then perform with each node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate and generate the combined result.

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".bx li");
GM_setClipboard(
  // convert nodelist to array
  // for older browser use [].slice.call(list)
  Array.from(list)
  // iterate and get HTML content
  .map(function(e) {
    return e.innerHTML;
  })
  // combine the HTML contents
  .join('')
)
```

---

Alternatively, we can use simply for loop which would be better since we don't need to create an extra array.

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".bx li");

// initialize string variable for HTML
var html = '';

// iterate over the nodelist using for loop
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  // append the HTML content to the string variable
  html += list[i].innerHTML;
}

GM_setClipboard(html);
```

Comment: So to a) create array in the heap b) call function for each element in it then c) walk through elements of the array to join them ... No wonder that we have so heavy web sites...

Answer (score 0):

You need to walk through the list and compose required HTML string:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".bx li");
var html = "";
for(var n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) 
   html += list[n].outerHTML;
```